# How does the glycocalyx of cells attach together if they are negatively charged?

Tags: cell-biology, cell-membrane

**Context**

> Thus, the entire outside surface of the cell has a loose carbohydrate coat called the glycocalyx.
>
> The carbohydrate moieties attached to the outer surface of the cell has several important functions:
>
> 1. Many of them have a negative electrical charge, which gives most cells an overall negative surface charge that repels other negatively charged objects.
> 2. The glycocalyx of some cells attaches to the glycocalyx of other cells, thus attaching cells to one another.

[Guyton and Hall, Textbook of Medical Physiology, 2nd South Asia Edition ( w.r.t 13e)]

Here, two contrasting statements are written. They seem to differ in the context. Actually, I tried searching for more about glycocalyx and saw the same written in many places without explanation. I cannot understand that how the cells can be attached, if both of them are negatively charged.